# Easy C library to access MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql, c

Any suggestions for a real simple C library to query a single MySQL table, nothing fancy here. Just doing a single select * from a table. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

MySQL comes with an [API](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/c.html) for using C with it.

Answer (score -2):

MySQL has its own C API:
[See MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/c.html)

Comment: Way to parrot an answer of the poster 29 mins before you!

Comment: I didn't notice Mimisbrunnr also added the link to the manual